# Non Port 80 Web Server and Pretty URL's

Tags: mod-rewrite, proxy, ip, port

This is a "Blocked Port 80" related question, but maybe something a bit unique.  I've yet to find a good answer.  It's more academic than anything as I know running a production server at your house is a ridiculous idea.

I'm running a development server (LAMP) at my home but my ISP blocks port 80.  The DNS for my domain is set up to "URL Redirect" to my IP and port number.  My router is port-forwarding to my server, and I have Apache set up so it's listening on port 8081.

The issue is that when you access the domain, the URL in the browser is resolved from my domain name to the IP and port number, and is displayed as such.  **For example, you type "www.banana.com" into the browser, the site is displayed but now the URL is shown as "12.23.456.11:8081".**

Is there any way to fix this so that the domain name does not become IP and port number?

Can you use Apache proxy functionality somehow?

Could you use mod_rewrite to change the IP and port number back to the domain name?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This question has three parts. First the issue of the domain: in order to substitute a domain name in place of an IP address you need some name server that can map your desired name to an address. This is at the host level and not the port level so a domain name will encompass all ports you might host from it. If you are using your home Internet connection (which I suspect you are since you talk about a blocked port) then you need to take into account that from time to time your public IP address can change. Your options are to pay for (or request) a static IP from your ISP or use a dynamic DNS service that can rapidly update their records as your IP address changes.

As for your port number. Mod_rewrite only handles the path part of a URL, for using different ports internally you want mod_proxy. The Apache web sever with mod_proxy would be configured to listen on the public port you want (that I assume is port 80) then mod_proxy would take incoming requests and send them to another web server on a different port (or even different server). To the outside user this happens invisibly.  The problem is if your ISP wont let you host your site on port 80 then it logically won't let you proxy from port 80.  To get around this would be a little harder. Personally I would look at a virtualized server from people like Rackspace or Linode. You would get (for relatively little money) a fully configurable server on the open Internet with no restrictions on port usage and a static IP. Even better if you mess something up you can just virtually delete your server and start over with a fresh OS image.

Finally the clean URLs your question title suggests. It's possible this wasn't part of your actual question but just in case, mod_rewrite is a smart module that can let you map clean URLs like `/cars/Toyota/1997` and turn them into more ugly requests like `/cars.php?make=Toyota&year=1997`. Clean URLs not only look better they make it easier to reorganize web code behind the scenes as your web site evolves.

One last thing, and its amazing to me that this question has gone so long without even a comment about this but, this question is really not a good fit for StackOverflow. Possibly [ServerFault.com](https://serverfault.com/). Good luck! :)